# is it safe to expose customer ID or credit card ID from STRIPE to the public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for payment in my platform. Stripe provides me with IDs for the objects I can access in my account,

things like customer_id, which is like something `cus_6DUY9LB2ih5Pdy`

or credit card id like `card_1613mtB177tQO9RpJRQEFLcV`

If i had a delete link which references those ID like so

```
http://mywebapp.com/user/card_1614UyB177tQO9RpKy5Ysw10
```

for example, that link will delete the card from stripe and from my local DB

Is it safe for me to expose these IDs to the public?

can someone potential do malicious things with the card ID(like creating a charge?)

Comment: Those ids are specific to your account and only work with your secret key so that wouldn't be unsafe and out of scope from PCI but I would say it's always better to use your own ids instead of exposing those.

Comment: One more tip, avoid to expose primary key id, preffer to use a GUID for this kind of sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

To get an answer marked on this, confirming what @koopajah said in the comment on the question years ago:

> Those ids are specific to your account and only work with your secret key

So they are safe (nobody else can use them), but you may not want to expose these or build too much dependency around them. Instead, use your own data representation as a reference to them.